# Dagger footnote for authors in report document class

Tags: footnotes, thesis, report

For my thesis, I am using the report document class and want a dagger footnote on my name on the title page (all other footnotes are supposed to be numbered). It seems however that using either `\thanks` or `\footnote`, I get numbers. All information on this issue seems to be assuming the article document class, as none of the solutions that I've tried have worked for report. So how would I make the author footnote a dagger symbol using the report document class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Temporarily change the footnote symbol:

```
\documentclass{report}

\title{text}
\author{names\thanks{text}}

\begin{document}

{
\makeatletter
\addtocounter{footnote}{1} % to get dagger instead of star
\renewcommand\thefootnote{\@fnsymbol\c@footnote}%
\makeatother
\maketitle
}

text\footnote{text}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Fantastic. This worked! Thank you.